# Could not find file 'E:\Programa\DTR\DTR\bin\Debug\OpenFileDialog1

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

This is my code.

The value of `openfiledialog1` under the following.

```
If OpenFileDialog1.FileName <> Nothing Or OpenFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then
   txtempname.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Substring(
       OpenFileDialog1.FileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1,
       (OpenFileDialog1.FileName.IndexOf(".", 0) - (OpenFileDialog1.FileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)))
End If



Dim fsreader As New FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim bread As New BinaryReader(fsreader)
Dim imgbuffer(fsreader.Length) As Byte
bread.Read(imgbuffer, 0, fsreader.Length)
fsreader.Close()

commstring = "Update EMPLOYEES SET EMPID=@EMPID, EMPNAME=@EMPNAME, DEPARTMENT=@DEPARTMENT, STATUS=@STATUS, pic_file=@picfile WHERE EMPID = @EMPID"

con.Open()

cmd = New OleDbCommand(commstring, con)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPID", txtempno.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPNAME", txtempname.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEPARTMENT", txtaddep.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS", cbostat.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pic_file", imgbuffer)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

Comment: [mcve] please. What is `OpenFileDialog1`?

Comment: ["Thanks" is redundant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Instead, take that time to improve your question.

Comment: Could not find question,  Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @user202729 i will use Openfiledialog1 for uploading and saving image in my database. error in the above sentence.

Comment: @Plutonix this is the error Could not find file 'E:\Programa\DTR\DTR\bin\Debug\OpenFileDialog1

Comment: Can you add what file path you selected in OpenFileDialog vs what's the value of OpenFileDialog1.FileName?

Comment: Please format your code with [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: @Sunil 
        If OpenFileDialog1.FileName <> Nothing Or OpenFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then
            txtempname.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Substring(
           OpenFileDialog1.FileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1,
         (OpenFileDialog1.FileName.IndexOf(".", 0) - (OpenFileDialog1.FileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)))

        End If

Comment: @sunil thanks for you help to ask the value of OpenFileddalog1. i hope you saw this changing.

Comment: Your `If` statement is wrong.  You should be using `AndAlso` and not `Or`.  Your `If` statement will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying  `If OpenFileDialog1.FileName` instead of  `If Not OpenFileDialog1.FileName`.

I guess you're trying to get the filename without extension? If so, there's no need for all those '`IndexOf`'. He's a simplified version that should help.

```
    If Not OpenFileDialog1.FileName Is Nothing And Not OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "" Then
        txtempname.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    End If
```

(`Imports System.IO` for `Path`)

Comment: Remember to also check for cancel.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If this is the correct answer can you upvote or mark as answered? I'm new here and still trying to get my first reputation. Thank you.